# Formatação do Label do INPUT[TYPE=RADIO]

Tags: formatação

Bom dia a todos.
Me perdoem se esta pergunta já foi feita aqui mas procurei e não achei nada semelhante.
Estou montando uma pesquisa para ser utilizada em **smartphones** e tenho algumas opções ( input[type=radio] ) com labels extensos. Isso está quebrando as linhas de forma desagradável (imagem anexa).
Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como arrumar isso, ou seja, a linha debaixo ficar alinhada na coluna da primeira linha ?
Segue o código HTML em anexo.
Obrigado desde já.

```html
<label>13. Qual &eacute; a categoria com maior dificuldade na compra ?</label>
<div>
 <input type='radio' name='ck_categoria' value='1' class='checkbox-template' style='' onclick=''>RA&Ccedil;&Otilde;ES
 <br>
 <input type='radio' name='ck_categoria' value='2' class='checkbox-template' style='' onclick=''>MEDICAMENTOS
 <br>
 <input type='radio' name='ck_categoria' value='3' class='checkbox-template' style='' onclick=''>BIOL&Oacute;GICOS
 <br>
 <input type='radio' name='ck_categoria' value='4' class='checkbox-template' style='' onclick=''>HIGIENE E BELEZA (COSM&Eacute;TICOS)
 <br>
 <input type='radio' name='ck_categoria' value='5' class='checkbox-template' style='' onclick=''>LIMPEZA (AREIA, TAPETE, FRALDA E DESINFETANTES)
 <br>
 <input type='radio' name='ck_categoria' value='6' class='checkbox-template' style='' onclick=''>ACESS&Oacute;RIOS
 <br>
 <input type='radio' name='ck_categoria' value='7' class='checkbox-template' style='' onclick=''>SNACKS
 <br>
 <input type='radio' name='ck_categoria' value='8' class='checkbox-template' style='' onclick=''>OUTROS (favor especificar)
 <br>
 <input type='text' disabled id='ck_categoria_outros' name='ck_categoria_outros' data-msg='' class='form-control' value='' maxlength='200'>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, busque [edit] sua pergunta adicionando o código HTML de forma a construir um [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma como vc montou sua lista não está legal, além de não estar semântica.

Sugiro que use um `UL/LI` com `display:flex` assim vc consegue o que quer e deixa as coisas melhor formatadas no HTML, usando uma listagem e uma `<label>` para o `<input>`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="n1">
    <label for="n1">label</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="n2">
    <label for="n3">label muito muito muito muito longa</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="n3">
    <label for="n3">label muito muito muito muito longa</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Ficou perfeito.

Comment: @cfreitasc sem problemas 